# Here SDK - Custom raster layers not working

Tags: here-api

I am using Here SDK Navigation Edition for Android. With Lite Edition I was able to use several custom raster layers on the map, but after migrating to Navigation Edition this does not work.

The only way to see a layer is to use renderedLast() of the [MapLayerPriorityBuilder](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-navigate/4.10.4.0/dev_guide/topics/custom-map-styles.html). However, doing this did hide also all map markers! Any other way just showed the Here's map scheme. No custom layers.

What I want to achieve is to have the background map from custom opaque layer as well as show further transparent layers on top of that. Naturally all the map markers should be visible too. How can I do this?

Edit:

This code brings the layer visible and hides all markers:

```
 MapLayerPriority priority = new MapLayerPriorityBuilder()
        .renderedLast()
        .build();
```

While this keeps the layer hidden

```
 MapLayerPriority priority = new MapLayerPriorityBuilder()
        .renderedFirst()
        .build();
```

The actual layer is built like in the example:

```
MapLayer mapLayer = new MapLayerBuilder()
                 .forMap(mapView.getHereMap()) // mandatory parameter
                 .withName(dataSourceName + "Layer") // mandatory parameter
                 .withDataSource(dataSourceName, MapContentType.RASTER_IMAGE)
                 .withPriority(priority)
                 .withVisibilityRange(range)
                 .build();
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

No replies from HERE support team, but I did some digging into the example code and the scene json it uses. I have not received access to HERE Style Editor. It appears that using the following code does the trick:

```
        MapLayerPriority priority = new MapLayerPriorityBuilder()
            .renderedAfterLayer("ocm_cartography")
            .build();
```

So the key here is to *know* the layer names of the NORMAL_DAY scheme. I'm now struggling with transparent layers, but that is another question.

Comment: For transparent layers, set rasterProviderConfig.hasAlphaChannel to true.